# Read AT somebody

Tags: meaning, prepositions

In the latest Game of Thrones episode there was a phrase:

- Septa Unella reads it to me. At me.
- Yes. yes she does enjoy reading at people.

What does it mean "to read at somebody" ?

Comment: BTW - We usually refer to TV show events as happening _"**In** the latest episode....."_  The same is true of movies, YouTube videos, books, and other forms of entertainment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implication here is probably that she is reading to someone who is not listening or does not want to be read to.

This little substitution of **at** for another preposition is common with *talk.*  If you *talk **with** someone*, then you two are engaging in meaningful dialog.  If you *[talk **at** someone](https://www.google.com/#q=%22talk%20at%22),* then they are *tuning you out.*  (Ignoring you.)

*Read **at*** is new to me, but it seems like understanding it in the same way works in context.

> Septa Unella reads it to me. At me.  *(Septa is reading to me.  She didn't care that I wasn't listening.  )*
>
> Yes. yes she does enjoy reading at people. *(Yes.  She likes reading even though people don't care what she is reading to them.  At them)*

Comment: Why person would enjoy reading even if somebody does not listen?

Comment: "Enjoy" might not be the best word.  Maybe "feel smug, self-satisfied, or superior" might be better.  Maybe like a religious zealot reading from their holy books, believing they are saving souls by reading to people who aren't listening.  I don't know Septa's particular motivation, because I haven't ever seen Game of Thrones.